# JSP delete row and save

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, dojo

I am working in **Spring MVC 2, Jsp, Dojo, Javascript**.

Actually I am populating Jsp page table-grid with list of objects coming in form command object. Let say 3 records displayed in grid. I am deleting third record with JavaScript getElementById.. delete-row/removeChild functions. That record is deleted from presentation i.e. grid. Now when I save this. It takes 3 records to server side instead of 2. It should take 2 records because the third record was deleted. I am using Dojo to dragNdrop grid rows.

Comment: There is probably a bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: I don't know, because you forgot to include your code in the question.

Comment: Problem is not with code. When I add new row through javascript. This new row goes to server side. But when I delete any row it also go to server side which should not be... I think browser or some binding-container is not being updated accordingly? What do u say?

Comment: I say that the probability of being a bug in your code vs. the browser is 99.99% vs. 0.01%. But no one can tell for sure since we don't have access to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not resolve issue but another logic fulfills my need. Spring form tags were used to bind this for with objectclass. Converting deleted item row's id to negative and hiding this row at client side does the trick. When form submits this negative id converted to positive value and deleted from DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a grid component that maintains a datastore - e.g. the [DojoX DataGrid](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html), you might be removing the markup for the row, but not telling the datastore to purge the row data. When the save occurs, the datastore sends all three rows.

If you are using the DataGrid, you should [delete the row from the DataStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#adding-and-deleting-data), which will be reflected automatically in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this kind of issue, I always check the cache related headers in my response.

Could it be that the http request supposed to fetch saved data from the server in order to refresh the view doesn't hit the server, but instead hit the browser cache?